# Python: Formatting int to 2 places

Tags: python

My function calculates numbers, which sometimes will be more than 100. If they are larger than 100 I want to remove the extra digits.

For example, lets say I have

```
percent=950
```

I want it to be reprinted as

```
percent=95
```

I do not want to convert to string, so I would rather not use slicing...

Comment: What about dividing by 10: `int(950/10)`  will give 95?

Comment: So if the number is `101`. Do you want it to print the value `10` or `100`?

Comment: That sounds about right #Marcin. Likewise you could always use ratios so that your calculations never exceed 100%

Comment: @Marcin that doesn't work. what if the percent is larger than 3 digits? c'mon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to have a test to see if the number is `> 100`, you could do it like this:

```
>>> num = 95001
>>> int(str(num)[:2])
95
```

Though I'm unsure if you want to slice off the extra digits or store them as a decimal value. If you want to store them as a decimal value, go with mu's answer (making sure to cast at least one of the types to `float` if you're in Python 2 so you use float division).

Comment: Its funny how OP explicitly asks for `I do not want to convert to string, so I would rather not use slicing` and then goes on to use the answer that does exactly that :)

Comment: @mu Yeah, it's pretty strange. I'm thinking they didn't realize how easy it is to convert back to int after that.